# ¿Cómo compactar/reducir código de OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Este código lo repito hasta 4 veces, una vez por cada botón (bt1, bt2, bt3 y bt4). Sólo cambia donde pone bt1 que lo reemplazo por los otros botones.

Seguro que hay una forma de reducir el código para no repetir lo mismo 4 veces.
¿Pueden ayudarme?

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(SumasActivity.this, "1: "+bt1.getText()+" 2: "+ (n1 + n2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (bt1.getText().equals("" + (n1 + n2))) {
                    bt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5fba7d"));
                } else {
                    bt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f48024"));
                }
                // DELAY y PASA PANTALLA
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(stage>=5) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(SumasActivity.this, Inicio.class);
                            i.putExtra("dificultad", dificultad);
                            i.putExtra("stage", stage);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }else{
                            Intent i = new Intent(SumasActivity.this, SumasActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("dificultad", dificultad);
                            i.putExtra("stage", stage);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                }, 2000);
```

Comment: Consulta... será que es posible que todo lo que tienes despues de "void onClick" es posible meterlo en algún tipo de función de tal forma que solo llames a la función que contiene el código y no todo el código .

Comment: Puedes hacer lo que te propone @JaphSxas o simplemente crear un objeto de clase tipo OnClickListener y asignarle valor en el constructor de la clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría ayudarte, pruebalo y comentas tus resultados.

Función que devuelve la escucha OnClick.

```
public AdapterView.OnClickListener funcion(final Button bn){
    return new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bn.getText().equals("" + (n1 + n2))) {
                bn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5fba7d"));
            } else {
                bn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f48024"));
            }
            // DELAY y PASA PANTALLA
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(stage>=5) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(SumasActivity.this, Inicio.class);
                        i.putExtra("dificultad", dificultad);
                        i.putExtra("stage", stage);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else{
                        Intent i = new Intent(SumasActivity.this, SumasActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("dificultad", dificultad);
                        i.putExtra("stage", stage);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    };
}
```

Esta función le pasas al botón en su metodo setOnClickListener

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(funcion(bt1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 opciones:

- Utilizar subclases, pasando el boton especifico como parametro del listener

  ```
  bt1.setOnClickListener(new MyListener(bt1));

  class MyListener implements AdapterView.OnClickListener {
      private Button btn;
      MyListener(Button btn) {
          this.btn = btn;
      }
      @Override
      public void onClick( View view) {
          //codigo
      }
  }
  ```
- Simplemente extraer la logica comun en un metodo

  ```
  bt1.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener {
      @Override
      public void onClick( View view) {
          logica(bt1);
      }
  });

  public void logica(Button btn) {
      //codigo
  }
  ```

Comment: y el comentario asociado a la votacion negativa?